# What powers the puddle jumpers?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

So far as I can tell, a power source for the puddle jumpers hasn't been identified, although they seem to require power. What is the source of this power?

Comment: "Rechargeable power core" is all the stargate wiki says, I'm guessing you're looking for more, so won't submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Gateship or "Puddle Jumper" power plant has never been clearly defined. It is, however, a multi-purpose vehicle whose power plant can be drained, like a battery and recharged.**

- Many of these ships have been found in Ancient facilities with their power plant offline but able to be recharged and returned to service.
- The power plant has an output sufficiently high enough to use the vehicle as an interstellar exploration craft, capable of cloaking, shielding, submerging and even as a disposable drone/remote weapons platform. With modifications it could even power a low-end hyperdrive system for a brief period.
- The power plant has been jury-rigged to provide shield power to Atlantis, converted to be utilized to power a time-machine as well as being used as an alternate reality jump-ship.
- Given the nature of the Ancients the device likely functions using a crystalline power source, able to be recharged and considered common and unremarkable. Such "rechargeable power cores" were likely ubiquitous in Ancient society the same way a car battery might be in ours, with the understanding their power output would be the equivalent of an aircraft carrier's nuclear power facility. *(I rate it that highly simply because it couldn't be less than that and be useful as a power source for any systems in Atlantis otherwise.)*

[image: Gateship Cutaway]

*Gateship Cutaway Image*

Answer (score 0):

Frankly the "power crystal" technology so commonly used throughout Scifi is little more then magic really, perhaps not for storing energy within its atomic lattice (Though the amounts are quite impressive, but with the addition of exotic particle interactions all kinds of magic opens up, see http://www.nationstates.net/nation=system-lord_baal/detail=factbook/id=3075  and http://gwvf.wikia.com/wiki/Kiron_Theory) but as far as generating it....

But, this "rechargeable power core" seems very vague to myself, I find it would make far more sense for the Jumpers power plant to function along the same lines as a DHD's cold fusion cell with an accompanying "rechargeable power core". Ancient technology seems to change very little over millenia, leading me to assume that they follow if it aint broke dont fix it, or they had just advanced to the point where further advancement was too difficult or not really worth it as they were top dog in this galactic cluster and had no need to advanced further. Anyways, a DHD's power cell lasts for about 50 million years according to canonical timeline, (although the Ancients may have charged the DHD before they left Earth and the SG timeline is fraked.) give or take, 5-10 million minimum, so they are pretty robust. So, they would be perfectly suited to powering a Gateship.